# Using <p> instead of <input> in email form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have used `<p>` tag to print the output calculated by Javascript. Now I have to send the value I have printed in the `<p>` through an email form. This is a piece of code I have. Are there ways to grab the value of the `<p id="total" name="total"></p>` and send it to email using PHP?

```
<h3><p>Total Estimated Cost : </p><b><p id="total" name="total"></p></b></h3>

var times="2.5 hours";
var person="1";
var total="$92.00";
document.getElementById("times").innerHTML=times;
document.getElementById("person").innerHTML=person;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=total;
```

Comment: `<p>` tags do not have name attributes...

Comment: Are you able to modify the output, or are you stuck needing to do something with the <p> elements?

Comment: i am able to modify the output. what i need to do is grab the output value i printed in p and send it to email..

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden input that recieves value from P tag on submit using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to pass the value to a php using `window.location`

```
var times="2.5 hours";
var person="1";
var total="$92.00";
document.getElementById("times").innerHTML=times;
document.getElementById("person").innerHTML=person;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=total;

function sendMail() {
    window.location = "sendMail.php?total=" + total
}
```

And then a link in your page

```
<a href="#" onclick="sendMail();">Send Mail</a>
```

Comment: can i use  window.location = "sendMail.php?total=" + total && price= " + price && person=" + person if i have to send more than one values...

Comment: window.location = "sendMail.php?total=" + total + "&price=" + price + "&person=" + person

Answer (score 0):

the `<p>` is a *weird* way to act as a value holder :) I would probably use `<input>` as quick solution or even data-set for the sake of flexibility.

One way to send dynamically a value up (to the server) is through [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and since you're using jquery (tag-wise), there is the function [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), which lets you send the data without a page refresh.

A typical code is that:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"your.php",
   type:"POST",
   async:false,
   data:{total:$("#total").html(),times:$("#times").html(),person:$("#person").html()},
   success:function(data) {
      alert("sent ok");
   }
});
```

in your hypothetical `your.php` file, your total value with come as `$_POST["total"]`.

Then, you want to use [mail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) but i strongly recommend using something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) to send an *HTML* mail, which will solve a lot of future headaches.

Comment: Here is the problem.. i used a from and used Jquery to calculate and then printed final values to p tags. Now i need to send 3 values to PHP form and then send the values to email. all the other fields are ok but i cant capture the output values to send to the PHP form..
Here is the link to the form: http://thectiweb.com/booknow_new/index.html

Here is the link

Comment: Then all you have to do is calling the above `$.ajax` to send to printed values which are inside the `<p>`

Comment: I dont understand how you can't `capture` the output values, You get them via `document.getElementById()` or by the `jquery` i shown above.